# Listeners not working for Chrome Rich Notification API ManifestV2- Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm unable to enter into any of the listener functions for notifications API with manifest V2. I'm able to execute the callback function after Notification is displayed. Also I can see that the `chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener` is present while using in debugging mode.

Here's my manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "Learning",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.3",
  "description": "Notification Popup",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["script.js"],
    "persistent" : false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ajax.googleapis.com/; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**script.js**

```
var options = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Someone just replied to your mail",
    message: "You have been hired in our company",
    iconUrl: "stackIcon.PNG"
}
chrome.notifications.create(options,function() {
    console.log('Notification Callback');
});

chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function() { 
    console.log('notification Clicked');

});
chrome.notifications.onClosed.addListener(function() {
    console.log('notification Closed');
});
chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function() {
    console.log('notification Button Clicked');
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    console.log('runtime onInstalled');
})
```

console.log results

```
Notification Callback
```

Comment: Are you sure your manifest.json and script.js are up to date? For example, I noticed your manifest.json doesn't compile because there's an extra comma after "notifications". I fixed the extra comma and copied your exact code and I'm not being able to reproduce your issue, since I'm getting all console.log callbacks normally on my background page...

Comment: Sorry that , is a typo. I'll fix it. But yes I'm unable to get any logs. Do i have to unpack the extension and try it again?

Comment: You shouldn't need to unpack it, just reload it. Maybe you forgot to click the "Reload" button next to your extension on chrome://extensions/ ? That way you might be seeing an older version of your extension, because I've tried out your exact code here and it works.

Comment: I tried reload button multiple times. But the strange thing is, Whenever i click the reload button i get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` and when i exeute `location.reload()` in background chrome console, I dont get that error.

Comment: That error usually has two causes: either the "notifications" permission isn't set correctly, or you're calling the chrome.notifications.create method from a content script instead of a background script. I'd suggest creating a separate folder with just your manifest.json, script.js, and stackIcon.PNG and "loading unpacked" that new folder into Chrome as a new extension to see if you're still getting the error in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate bug in Chromium Extensions, https://crbug.com/1168477, it has been fixed in version 91 canary.